# node.d.ts and requirejs.d.ts throwing compilation errors

Tags: typescript, azure, typescript2.0, azure-devops-extensions

**Scenario :**

- I have recently upgraded my Azure DevOps extension from typescript 1.8 to 3.2.1.
- The same time I've been upgrading the other dependencies and type
  definitions. 
  As a result I currently have requirejs type 2.1.20 and
  Node.js type 10.12
   (version numbers as per the *.d.ts).

Which throws below errors while compiling:

> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(7696,5): error TS2300: Duplicate
>   identifier 'mod'. node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts(38,11):
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'mod'.
>   node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts(422,13): error TS2403:
>   Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable
>   'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.

I understand there are some sort of similar questions in the net, but I don't see a proper answer to any.
Appreciate if you could have a look and let me know how to fix this.